If possible help me to make this question correct to be asked at some if the stackexchange form m

I have a question about my Politics Stack Exchange post: Seeking Political Insights: Collaborative Approach to Leverage Microsoft and OpenAI's $2 Million Fund for Palestine
So as I am not familiar I asked to make it better to be corrected to ask in some  stackexchange's forum
We need the help of experts for the catastrophic situation in ghazal and if possible make it approved.
Thanks 

To be honest, it looked like an attempt to promote the project, rather than asking anything on topic for this site.  $2M is certainly welcome for Gaza, but not sure spending it on AI fluff is the best way to proceed.  Regardless of its utility or not, a question about any one particular donation by private entities would seem off topic for this site.  Though I could see international aid, including by private entities, being on topic under certain conditions.  Hypothetical example:  "How did the Gates Foundation enlist the collaboration of X communities despite Y with their malaria project?"

There are a number of problems I see in this question.
Minor problems that might be fixable, but are a sign that there is something more fundamentally wrong with the question:

The title isn't phrased as a question. This is a hint that what you are posting isn't really a question, or at least not a properly thought out one.
You are asking multiple questions at once. A good question on Stack Exchange should ask one question and one question only.
"This post has written by the help of AI": I can tell due to the way it's bloated with meaningless phrases which make it longer and make it sound more eloquent, but don't transport any relevant information or meaning. That's the problem with today's text generation machine learning models: it's greatest talent is creating lots of text without saying much of substance. Which is one of many reasons why AI-generated content isn't welcome here.

Major problems that are probably not possible to fix while retaining your intention:

"I am initiating a discussion within the Politics Stack Exchange community": Politics Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. It's a question&answer website. If you want to start a discussion, then a more debate-oriented community would be more fitting for your post.
The questions are very open-ended idea generation and brainstorming questions. Questions which have no right or wrong answers aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange Q&A system. See also "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" on the help center.
You are very obviously promoting something. Either the AI in Democracy fund in general, or specifically the political idea to use it for Palestine. Neither form of promotion is welcome in this community.


I don't think that question can be salvaged as I don't see how the use of a private fund would be in topic here even if it is for political use.
